# Efficiently shading multiple county polygons in MapBox (web and mobile)

Tags: mapbox

I'm working on a visualization project where I'd like to use a fill color over US Counties that fall into my data set. (weather data)

I have shapefiles for the counties, but there are hundreds (if not thousands) of points per county, and some parts of my data can cover 20+ counties. I'm thinking that manually drawing the polygons may not be the approach to take.

Is there an efficient approach using the MapBox SDKs for accomplishing what I'm trying to do? I'd like to do it both in web and mobile if possible, but I'll start with web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look into [TileMill](http://tilemill.com) in order to make custom map tiles with your source data. Then, you can use those tiles on web and mobile both.

https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/add-shapefile
https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/styling-polygons/
https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/crashcourse/exporting/
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/layers/
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/#tile_sources__protocol

Comment: I see on the MapBox plans page that Geographic Features are limited to 2000/map for all plans. I've got 3000+ polygons representing US Counties - am I out of luck?

Comment: Scott, I'm working on a mapping project that allows for millions of polygons. Check out gwikis.com and shoot me an email (address on site) if you're interested in beta testing.